# Area of one loop of the curve $r=5\cos4\theta$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

Area of one loop of the curve $r=5\cos4\theta$

The area of one loop can be given by: $\frac{1}{2}\int^\frac{\pi}{8}_\frac{-\pi}{8}(5\cos4\theta)^2\,d\theta$. However this gives me an answer of $\frac{25}{8}\pi$ while the answer says its $\frac{25}{16}\pi$, why have I got double the area I should have calculated? Have I found the integral between the wrong values or is the answer for my question wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the integral is correct, it gives the correct answer. Something might be wrong in your computation...

Comment: May be, you forgot the factor $\frac 12$ in front

Comment: the integral which i have written has has the factor of 0.5 applied to it.

Comment: @H.Linkhorn How about you show your work step-by-step? This will be clearer than having to guess where you went wrong.